# Обособляется ли указательная частица "вот" в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

> Вот () пушистая звездочка, вот () мягкий шар, а вот () не похожие ни на что, кроме изобретательной фантазии русского кудесника, необыкновенные снежинки.

Comment: Да, интересно получилось. Всё зависит от того, с какой точки зрения взглянуть на это предложение. Русский язык — наука не точная.

Answer (score 3):

Уважаемые коллеги, не хочу ни с кем спорить об омонимичности частицы ВОТ, но давайте посмотрим с точки зрения синтаксиса.

*Вот пушистая звездочка, вот мягкий шар, а вот — не похожие ни на что, кроме изобретательной фантазии русского кудесника, необыкновенные снежинки.*

Такой тип предложения во всех грамматиках определяется как номинативное, назывное, так? Значит, это указательная частица (если б было наречие или местоимение — было бы двусоставное):
Валгина: "Указательные предложения, кроме значения бытия, существования, содержат указание на имеющиеся предметы и явления. Структурным признаком таких предложений являются указательные частицы *вот (вот и), вон, а вот.

Вот оно, глупое счастье с белыми окнами в сад* (Ес.); *Вон солнце, голубое небо... Воздух какой чистый* (Купр.); *А вот вокзал.  Вот и лес. Тень и тишина* (Т.)".

Тире может ставиться для логического деления простого предложения на словесные группы, чтобы уточнить или подчеркнуть смысловые отношения между членами предложения. Здесь как раз такой случай — возможно поставить тире даже во всех случаях, как прочитаешь, но напрашивается тире после А ВОТ, оно делит предл. на 2 части, подчёркивая логически значимость и удивительность именно снежинок.
Сейчас придаётся большое значение синтаксическим средствам изобразительности в школе, ученик должен был почувствовать эту семантику. Однако в методике проверки письменных работ такая пунктограмма считается факультативной, просто подчёркивается, но при выставлении оценки не засчитывается. Посмотрите в Вашей методичке, интонационное тире — факультативный или обязательный знак? Учитель обязан увидеть это, указать,  а ученику — снисхождение.
По общему правилу тире не должно быть, мы проверяем БАЗОВЫЕ знания.

Comment: Людмила, спасибо за развернутый ответ. Дело в том, что в методичке у нас это не прописано, про интонационное тире, могу спросить у преподавательницы, конечно, посоветоваться с ней ещё, контрольная то моя все-таки, думаю будет только плюсом такая находка.

Comment: А чем плоха моя логика, когда *"вот"*(*="это"*) является подлежащим, а все предложение двусоставными?

Comment: Потому что ВОТ может быть подлежащим в одном случае: "Вот-указательная частица".ЭТО - может:"Вот это - звёздочка"(вот-частица, это - местоимение - подлежащее). Ваш совет студентке обойдётся дорого, у неё контрольная по синтаксису, снизят оценку сразу. Сейчас только Шведова считает вот местоимением (считала, вечная ей память), остальные учёные склонны определять как частицу, выступающую в разных ролях.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила,за авторитетный источник. Я в своем ответе коротко написал об этом же, предварительно "посоветовавшись" со словарем Ожегова, где "вот" отмечается лишь как частица. Думаю, что все попытки выдать ее за местоимение несостоятельны. Данная частица в назывных предложениях усиливает значение указательности на конкретное подлежащее как грамматическую основу предложения

Comment: Валентин тоже авторитетный источник привёл - словарь Ожегова и Шведовой, у нас с Вами Ожегов 1977 года(под ред. её же), потом его дорабатывала Шведова(он в 1964 г. умер), наука же меняется, а она - автор РГ-80, в котором всё перевёрнуто, во всех источниках указывается общее мнение учёных страны, а в скобках - "РГ-80", там даже термины другие. Получается, что у одног Ож. одно мнение, а в совместном - другое, т.е. Шведовой.Не знаю, как к этому относиться, вероятно, просто надо знать и то, и другое и иметь своё мнение.

Answer (score 0):

Частицы не обособляются воообще, но в данном примере *"вот"* — указательное местоимение, выполняющее роль подлежащего, так что (исключительно ввиду пауз) можно поставить тире.

Comment: спасибо за ответ) дело в том, что я проверяю ученическое сочинение...и там у девочки нет тире... я засомневалась, школьники ведь не знают таких особенностей... и как судить их за такие ошибки потом... или вынести на поля, но при оценивании не учитывать?

Comment: По правилу, если подлежащее выражено местоимением, тире не ставится, так что это можно не считать за ошибку. Здесь интонационное тире, которое ставится по желанию автора. Можете просто рассказать это своей ученице.

Comment: хмм...рассказать я ей не смогу, т.к. с ней лично не знакома) нам на методике преподавания РЯ выдали сочинения учеников для проверки прежде всего нас, как будущих учителей) Но своей преподавательнице мне придется это как-то объяснять) Тогда если я тире не поставлю, а в последнем случае у меня между подлежащим и сказуемым же сравнительный оборот, я его просто запятыми обособляю получается... и у меня выходит запятая после "а вот"

Comment: Там нет сравнительного оборота, там есть определение, которое не обособляется, так как стоит перед определяемым словосочетанием, и обособленное дополнение (*"кроме..."*). Не надо ставить запятую после третьего *"вот"*.

Answer (score 0):

Указательная частица "вот" в предложении выполняет роль только частицы и никогда не бывает местоимением, поэтому в Вашем предложении тире абсолютно не нужно. Интонация здесь не играет никакой роли. Частицы не выделяются ни запятыми, ни тире

Comment: Первый попавшийся словарь: http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/28694